# PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain) Works only on Domain Admin

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

the following code works on domain admin. But not with user rights.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WinM
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        }
    }
}
```

If i run this as user i get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The connection cannot be established.
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ConnectionHandle..ctor(IntPtr value, Boolean disposeHandle)
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.Init()
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection..ctor(LdapDirectoryIdentifier identifier, NetworkCredential credential, AuthType authType)
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection..ctor(LdapDirectoryIdentifier identifier)
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection..ctor(String server)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ReadServerConfig(String serverName, ServerProperties& properties)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoServerVerifyAndPropRetrieval()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType, String name, String container, ContextOptions options, String userName, String password)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType)
   at WinM.Program.Main(String[] args) in
```

Have anybody an idea?

Comment: Local firewall?

Comment: no. Same computer with domain admin works :-(

Comment: Now i can run it. If i copy this code from the Network share locally. It works. Has anybody an idea why this doesn't work from a smb share?

Comment: No but thank you for this. I beat my head against this rock for 2 days before I ran across your comment here.  This was the issue I was running in to also. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, until I realized that the SMB folder was not shared for the user account that received the LdapException. After adding the user to the list with Change+Read permissions the problem was solved.

Comment: could you add some screenshot or detailed steps what needs to be done?